# How do we track the user flow in a website that doesn't have an authentication system?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Let's say the customer filled a form on the 3rd page he visited, how do we find out his flow.(Where did he come from, which links on the website he clicked, basically the entire flow till he filled in the form).

There is no login or any kind of authentication system on the website. Is there a way to monitor the user flow? I don't have much experience with google analytics. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you looking for the flow of all the visitors in General or every visitor?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. Every visitor. Also, i should able to track visitor flow based on their goal conversions.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_OiIyLC4cI

Comment: This is very complicated. At a basic level, how will you define paths? Do you want every single paths, or only paths used by x% or more users?  Do you want to know every single interaction they had, or only certain actions? Do you want to know users who completed a particular secondary goal?
At the very least, I would advise that you install timestamp/session/client tracking, see: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/.

Comment: @sdhaus I have already installed timestamp/session/client tracking. I need to know every single interaction of each user including their goal conversions. How can I map client tracking with my goal? Say for ex, if a user submits a form, then I should be able to track his flow and also the places elsewhere on my website where he has submitted the form. Success form submission will be my goal. And it is triggered by virtual URL.

Comment: Are you wanting to just read through logs? Or find general rules of behavioural engagement for a given conversion?

Comment: @sdhaus Need to find behavioural engagement for all the conversions.

Comment: So you just want to read through users interactions?

Comment: Yes. I want to read through user interactions for the people who have successfully submitted the form.

Comment: https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/course/6  is good to start with google analytics

Comment: @NomanKhan Thanks for the reply. Please read the question again. I have an app installed with GA. It is also tracking visitor, session, and timestamps of a user. I have triggered a goal for the form submission. My requirement is how to know the user flow for a particular goal. For ex, f a user submits a form, then I should be able to track his flow and also the places elsewhere on my website where he has submitted the form. Success form submission will be my goal. And it is triggered by virtual URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options to do this:

1) User Reports

See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_OiIyLC4cI - From @Ramankingdom comment

Go to Google Analytics > Audience > User explorer.
Create a custom segment for your form of interest (in terms of the event data), e.g. Advance Conditions > Filter Sessions to Include > Event Category Contains *Forms* > Event Action Contains *My Form of Interest*

The resulting window will show you each Client ID, the number of sessions each client has had, session duration.. etc, as well as goal conversion rate. Note that this is the overall goal conversion rate, and is not specific to a specified goal.

You can then explore the clients behavior across sessions and within session, and have a list of specific interactions that Google Analytics captured.

2) Custom Reports

The second option is to export all behavior using your Client, Session and Timestamp custom dimensions. For this you will need to create a custom report for the Three custom dimensions along with Page Path.

Once you have exported the page path data, you will need to repeat for events (as they need to be queried separately).

Once you have the exported data, you can then join your datasets and have a full csv output of each of your sessions. This then gives you the ability to review the process data of any session containing any interaction of interest.

This method is more complicated, but will provide you with more flexability in the long run.

**Limitations:** This will be constrained to the data that has been sent to GA. I.e if links are not tracked, you will not be able to determine every link the user clicked.

--- Update ---

If you want to understand the flow of a particular user, specific to an email enquiry or lead, then you will also need to capture a unique identifier. For example, you could have a hidden field with a randomly generated number. This randomly generated number would then be sent along with the email. In addition, this randomly generated number should be captured with the email enquiry event, allowing you to identify specific email enquiries, whilst abiding by the PII terms of GA.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how do we get a path for the person who completed filling the form? For ex: if a person fills a form with an email address as name@domain.com, now how do we find a path(user flow) of this specific person.

Comment: So is your question, how do I identify unique users in Google Analytics which match a back end system, then determine their user flow, without userID?

Comment: Yes. Basically i need to identify the user flow for the users who have filled the form

Comment: You need to be more specific. If it was only to fill in the form, then the above solution would work. If you want to integrate with a backend system to identify the flow of a particular enquiry, then that is different.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this can help you!? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using  google analytics and google tag manager

You can generate cutom report related to user flow ,device ,location etc.

The Users Flow report is a graphical representation of the paths users took through your site, from the source, through the various pages, and where along their paths they exited your site. The Users Flow report lets you compare volumes of traffic from different sources, examine traffic patterns through your site, and troubleshoot the efficacy of your site.

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1709395?hl=en
- https://www.orbitmedia.com/blog/user-flow-google-analytics/

you can find more details [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1713056?hl=en)

Go to analytics

[image]

find the page you want stats on where visitors went next. To do that, you need to click on that page and select "Explore traffic through here", which ultimately leads to another flow visualisation, but only includes traffic going to and from that page:

[image]

[image]

You an also define your custom events and get all information related to user.

Comment: This provides the generalized user flow for a particular website. I need to differentiate based on the form submission (considered as a goal here). For ex, if a user fills a form, I need to know his user flow in particular.

Comment: You can define custom tag in tag manager to get customized report                               https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164470?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a little help from the developer, I would do the following:

1 - detect IP address  using PHP : 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] more about IP address reading from PHP : [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

2 - Reading the REFERER page  in PHP I would use: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] , this will tell you what is the previous page that the user had clicked in to reach this page,

3- Set a Unique session using PHP and store the REFERER page on it incrementally along with the IP address
More about sessions in PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

4- Store the above in a mysql DB and create a view for it using one of the Charts libraries

Comment: This will not provide the exact solution. Because, user IP won't be same at all point of time.

Comment: yes true,  you may also use cookies to save users data (session, IP )